# Using timestamp in where with count in having clause

Tags: mysql

I am trying to use a datediff function in my where clause and need to use a count function in having clause but I need to use OR function ie select loans from clients in the past 2 months or count of loans should be more than 50

I tried to use UNION clause wherein I specify the datediff part in one part of the code and the count function in the other part but I am getting duplicate values because of the count function.

```
where FundedBit = 1  
and SellerStatusTypeId = 1 -- Approved  
and lu.DelegatedUnderwritingBit = 1
and cml.LastFileDeliveryCompletedDtTm is not Null
group by   
p.PrimaryEmailAddrTxt,  
s.SellerSalesExecPersonId,  
s.SellerPartyId,  
s.SellerNum,  
s.PartyName ,
having (count(lc.LoanId) >= 50 or (cml.LastFileDeliveryCompletedDtTm <= convert(date,DATEADD(month, -2, GETDATE()))))  ----I need output if either of this two gets executed
```

I am getting an error like "Column 'cml.LastFileDeliveryCompletedDtTm' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause"

Comment: Yep, the error is pretty self explanatory. You can only use columns named in the `GROUP BY` clause, or aggregated columns. Maybe you wanted that condition in the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: I can use that condition in a where clause but how will I use the OR operator then?

Comment: You'll need to rethink that condition. What the error says is that the column `cml.LastFileDeliveryCompletedDtTm` **is not available** in that section of the SQL since the result set is "aggregated" at this point. There are no single columns anymore, but only sums, avgs, mins, maxs, etc. Do you see the point?

Comment: Would that `LastFileDeliveryCompleteDtTm`
 be the actual last file delivery complete date for that group clause? If so, do `MAX(cml.LastFileDeliveryCompletedDtTm)`
 instead.